# Security exception in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have developed an Azure Project bind to an ASP .NET MVC4 application using Entity framework CodeFirst, when I deploy my Azure Cloud Service in local it works well, but as soon I deploy on Azure it throws me an SecurityException. bellow you can see picture the stack trace using Intellitrace. I have runned my Visual Studio in Administration mode but it still fails.

[image: error]

You got any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For security purposes Registry access is restricted for **ASP.NET Applications**. It looks like you are trying to write to the **System Event Log**.

Before your application can write to the **Event Log**, you need to [create the event source as an administrator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842795). You can do this [via `EventLog.CreateEventSource()`](http://pshscripts.blogspot.com/2009/02/new-customeventlogps1.html), but this needs to be done as part of an [[*elevated*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129545.aspx#code-snippet-4)] [**role startup task**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) using [Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj130675.aspx).

Web applications don't typically use windows event logging since they are lesser privileged - they often use a tracing subsystem (*ETW, etc.*) or log to a database or file system directly. A possible alternative to this is to [enable tracing via `DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411522.aspx) and [WAD integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx).

Comment: Ok, but I never wanted to write to the System Event Log, where it could came from?

Comment: Do you have a [`WebRole.cs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.aspx) - if so what's in it? Did you add **Trace Listeners** to your `web.config`? There are numerous places this could be - you just need to search your project.

Comment: I don't have any WebRole.cs and I don't find Trace Listeners. Want I need to search?
I try in the same time your method with the EventLog.CreateEventSource()

Comment: It could be in a dependent library component you are using. What dependencies does your MVC app use? You could always [RDP into your role instance](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-configure-a-cloud-service/) and [temporary grant control to the registry key (*`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog`*)](http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2009/12/02/iis7-web-application-writing-to-event-log-generates-security-exception/). Then you could see what is being written to the system event log as a clue. ;-)

Comment: Looking at RoleEnvironment in Reflector shows that it is the WindowsAzure library that is making the EventLog write request.  Which makes me think there is a configuration problem.